# Using IF statements to create an error message if my function doesn't apply to my data in my sheet

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am just trying to create a message to say "Error. Value Invalid" for when I click yes but the function searchOutput() doesn't apply to the data that I have given it. I know my first IF statement works perfectly, however, I am failing to figure out how to create my invalid message. Any suggestions?

```js
function message() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var button = ui.alert("Search for Minimum Output Values", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  
  if(button == ui.Button.YES){searchOutput();}
  
    (button == ui.Button.false)('Error. Value Invalid')
  
}
```

Comment: does searchOutput() return something or are you saying if something errors out inside of that function you want to be able to handle it?

Comment: searchOutput() is a function in another part of my script. So far I can activate this function which will ask me to run searchOutput() which looks for specific values within my dataset. However, I have multiple datasets that do not have the specific values that searchOutput() is looking for. So I would like to have an Error message displayed on the screen, which states "Error. Value Invalid" or something along those lines if after activating this code up here doesn't find the values I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement and if `searchOutput` fails to execute a pop up message will appear in your sheet and then `message` will be terminated with no errors:

```
function message() {
 try{searchOutput()}
 catch(e){Browser.msgBox('Error. Value Invalid')} 
}
```

[image]

Keep in mind with this approach some code from `searchOutput` will be executed and that is the code before the error occurs in `searchOutput`. I think this is what you want based on your comment under your question, let me know otherwise.

**References:**

- [Browser.msgBox(prompt)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgBox(String))
- [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)